# Reading column from a CSV and save into a List<List<String>> in java

Tags: java, dataframe, csv

I am trying to do a simple data frame project which can read, write and make changes from the imported CSV file. This is the CSV file content:

```
Name,Age,Salary
Lim,20,2000
Tan,20,3000
Mah,19,2500
Roger,10,4000
```

I'm trying to read the file and then export the data into columns and rows. And this is the code that I had write:

```
        String filePath = "\...\src\Book1.csv";
        String line;
        List<List<String>> COLUMNDATA = new ArrayList();
        List<List<String>> ROWDATA = new LinkedList();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                List<String> column = Arrays.asList(line.split(","));
                COLUMNDATA.add(column);

            }

            int numCols = COLUMNDATA.get(0).size();
            List<String> rowData = new ArrayList();
            for(int j = 0; j<numCols; j++){
                rowData.clear();
                for(int z = 0; z<COLUMNDATA.size();z++){
                    String [] temp = COLUMNDATA.get(z).toArray(new String[0]);
                    String temp1 = temp[j];
                    rowData.add(temp1);
                }
               
                ROWDATA.add(rowData);
           
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        System.out.println(COLUMNDATA.toString());
        System.out.println(ROWDATA.toString());
```

This is the output of the the code:

```
[[Name, Age, Salary], [Lim, 20, 2000], [Tan, 20, 3000], [Mah, 19, 2500], [Roger, 10, 4000]]
[[Salary, 2000, 3000, 2500, 4000], [Salary, 2000, 3000, 2500, 4000], [Salary, 2000, 3000, 2500, 4000]]
```

Can I ask why is the `ROWDATA` showing the duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work it's because the ROWDATA.add(rowData) ads the same reference to rowData every time, one solution is to clone the object:

```
    String filePath = "\...\src\Book1.csv";
    String line;
    List<List<String>> COLUMNDATA = new ArrayList();
    List<List<String>> ROWDATA = new LinkedList();

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            List<String> column = Arrays.asList(line.split(","));
            COLUMNDATA.add(column);
        }
        int numCols = COLUMNDATA.get(0).size();
        ArrayList<String> rowData = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int j = 0; j < numCols; j++){
            rowData.clear();
            for(int z = 0; z < COLUMNDATA.size(); z++){
                String[] temp = COLUMNDATA.get(z).toArray(new String[0]);
                String temp1 = temp[j];
                rowData.add(temp1);
            }
            ROWDATA.add((ArrayList<String>) rowData.clone());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    System.out.println(COLUMNDATA.toString());
    System.out.println(ROWDATA.toString());
```

Outputs:

```
[[Name, Age, Salary], [Lim, 20, 2000], [Tan, 20, 3000], [Mah, 19, 2500], [Roger, 10, 4000]]
[[Name, Lim, Tan, Mah, Roger], [Age, 20, 20, 19, 10], [Salary, 2000, 3000, 2500, 4000]]
```